# Fetch as Google not rendering single-page application (AngularJS) - how to show console logs output

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, web-crawlers, single-page-application

I have an SPA application, and it is not being rendered correctly by Google.  I tried going to Google Web Master toolkit, and use the `Fetch as google` feature.  This is showing just the HTML output from the server, and the bindings etc of AngularJS are not rendering.  The status is marked as `Complete`, and download time is `0.074 seconds`. Application takes longer than that to execute, so I'm assuming Javascript is not being executed.

My assumptions are two:

- Either Google is not executing javascript for some reason
- Javascript error(s) are not allowing the page to correctly execute

The website works fine if I enter with a normal browser. Is it possible to view the `console.log` output somehow of the `Fetch as Google` request?  Maybe there is some console error which is stopping the page from executing? Do you need to let google know that it is an SPA somehow?

Comment: in fetch as google there are option to choose the bot type. I hope you had chosen "Desktop" version.

Comment: Yes, I did choose Desktop version. I dont' think it makes a difference though

Comment: did you try fetch as google and render ? if Yes, did you see the errors it shows for the page content and libraries google is not able to fetch. For example: for most of map based pages , it throws error that google is not able to fetch maps js libraries.

Comment: Yes I did try.  It shows the splash page , which is bad cause that should be removed by AngularJS.  It seems that AngularJS isn't running.  There are no libraries which it couldn't fetch.  But then again, I cannot see any console errors if something went wrong!

Comment: I've got this problem too.  Will investigate and post here if I find a solution.